# How to cache images on disk with SDWebImage or AFNetworking in a huge CollectionView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, afnetworking

I am using `AFNetworking` in my app to download de Url, code and details of an image. I store all these `NSStrings` in a NSObject in those Objects in a `NSMutableArray`. I use that `NSMutableArray` to get the images with `SDWebImage`, asynchronously, but after some images are downloaded my app crashes with **`Received memory warning`** I have tried using the same method in `AFNetworking` and nothing happens. I use this method with both libraries.

```
[self.pictureImg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kDefaultLoadingImage]];
```

I would like to know how to `cache` the images on disk and how to clean the cache whenever I need it. I do not care if you use `AFNetworking` or `SDWebImage`. I use that method in my custom `cells`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use this [FastImageChache](https://github.com/path/FastImageCache) library. It is able to cache images on disk as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

call this method when you "Received memory warning"

[SDWebImageManager.sharedManager.imageCache clearMemory];

Answer (score 0):

try this,

SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];

[imageCache clearMemory];

Answer (score 0):

For this method ,AFNetworking itself handles the cache, unless you dont ignore the cache property of the NSURLRequest

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.profileImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_default"]
                             options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this! Use **__weak** for your cell in AFTNetworking

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLCache *cache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024     // 10MB. memory cache
                                                      diskCapacity:100 * 1024 * 1024     // 50MB. on disk cache
                                                          diskPath:nil];
    sessionConfiguration.URLCache = cache;
    sessionConfiguration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy;
```

In collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
 __weak YOUR_CUSTOM_CELL *cell = (YOUR_CUSTOM_CELL *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSURLRequest *requestL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [your_model.url_image stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]]];
[your_cell.your_image_view setImageWithURLRequest:requestL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    your_cell.your_image_view.image = image;
} failure:nil];
```

I hope it will help!